# Define functions at the top or at the bottom of a script?

Tags: python

In Python all functions must be defined before they can be accessed. This leaves two choices for writing a script:

1. Define the functions at the top:

   ```
   def f1():
       # something

   def f2():
       # something

   # Call f1
   f1()
   # Call f2
   f2()
   ```
2. Define the functions at the bottom:

   ```
   def main():
       # Call f1
       f1()
       # Call f2
       f2()

   def f1():
       # something

   def f2():
       # something

   # Call main() at the bottom, after all the functions have been defined.
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```

Coming from Fortran, I was used to defined functions at the bottom, but I've seen numerous Python scripts where defining them at the top seems to be prefered.

Is one of these options more Pythonic/recommended than the other? If so, why?

**(I am not asking for an "opinion", I'm asking for a well-argumented reason as to why either one of these is preferred, or if they are both considered equally valid.)**

Comment: I'm sorry to say but there is no chance to answer the question if it is not based on an opinion, with more or less arguments, code-style is subjective (also, in my opinion). That's the reason I voted to close it. But maybe another users vote in the future to open it. Also possible

Comment: No seems like a perfectly valid answer here.

Comment: @DamianLattenero Agree.

Comment: I'm going with "it depends". In particular, if the code might be used as part of a package, having it all in functions (option 2) may give more calling flexibility. But if if it's a well-designed stable stand-alone module, option 1 involves less code.

Comment: PEP8 is the bible on all Python styling and I do not believe it has an opinion on this. Perhaps bring it up on the Python forums. I agree with @DamiánRafaelLattenero, particularly after 4 years, this question probably will not find an evidenced answer.